# How to fix whitespace in python?

Tags: python, removing-whitespace

I am trying to convert inches into height and inches using the feet'inches format yet I cant seem to get rid of the whitespace in-between the characters.

```
height1 = height // 12
height2 = height % 12
print(height1, '\', height2)
```

this is my current code

`5 ' 9` this is the output
`5'9` i need this to be the output

Answer (score 0):

You can use string concatenation directly or an f-string.

```py
print(f"{height1}'{height2}")
```